# Max Size of UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel

Is there a maximum size for a UILabel?  I use a label to show network requests.  After a fair number of requests, the label stops word wrapping and truncates the trail.  At some point I'll have to save the logs to disk.  Any ideas on ways to show the logs without running into this truncation problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a UILabel. UILabel isn't meant for that much text. Use a UITextView with editing disabled. It will just start to allow scrolling when it runs out of space.